# Running JUnit against EJB

Tags: jakarta-ee, junit

I'm returning to Java EE after a lengthy absence, so I'm basically having to learn modern EE from scratch.  As part of that effort, I'm trying to learn by doing.  I have a functional sandbox to play in -- a simple app where the front end is backed by an EJB talking to the database via JPA.

To help me learn, I'm trying to set up some JUnit tests.  Unfortunately, they're not working, and since I'm not that far beyond the "Monkey see, monkey do" stage in a lot of respects, I'm stumped for how to fix the problem I'm seeing.

The following is the code I've got set up to test MyEJB, which is defined as `@Stateless` and `@LocalBean`.  (If it matters, I'm running Glassfish/Eclipse.)

```
public class MyEJBTest {
    private static EJBContainer ejbContainer;

    private MyEJB myEJB; 

    @BeforeClass
    public static void startTheContainer() {
        ejbContainer = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer();
    }

    @Before
    public void lookupABean() throws NamingException {
        Object object = ejbContainer.getContext().lookup("java:global/simple-stateless/MyEJB");

        assertTrue(object instanceof MyEJB);

        myEJB = (MyEJB) object;
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void stopTheContainer() {
        if (ejbContainer != null) {
            ejbContainer.close();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testFind() {
        MyEntity myEntity = myEJB.find(1); 
        assertTrue(myEntity != null);
        assertEquals("First Row's Name", myEntity.getName());
    }

}
```

When I run this as a JUnit test, I get this error in the `startTheContainer()` call:

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: No EJBContainer provider available: no provider names had been found.
```

How do I fix this?  Or is my approach fundamentally wrong-headed somehow?

Answer (score 3):

Well, the `EJBContainer` API requires an `EJBContainerProvider` SPI implementation to be made available on the classpath. In the case of GlassFish, you'll need the embedded GlassFish JAR in your classpath. If you're using Maven, these `org.glassfish.extras:glassfish-embedded-all:3.1.1` are the coordinates to the 3.1.1 embedded version.

That said, you're better off using Arquillian to manage the lifecycle of the EJB container. While it may not be important now, it allow you to retain the option of deploying your EJB to a real container should you experience classpath pollution issues that are endemic to embedded Java EE containers.